# LIFERAY:Embed flash in Web Content Display

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a requirement where in a page is to be duplicated. This page has several image appearing with effects. It has images path stored in xml file & effects in flash files. I am using web content display, when i include just the plain swf files output is blank . I have included other .swf files in flash link they are working fine.But this .swf files need images so its blank. I have tried making a portlet, passing images in array and then giving transitions through javascript but the same effect is not achieved more over when i include portlet in my website my theme & other WCD is disturbed so i have dropped portlet way. But other than this how can the image be passed to WCD on a flash link.Please help as how the image & flash to be embeded in web content display.

My Actual page has xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<slides>
    <slide imageUrl="/images/home/A_397x930px.jpg" />
    <slide imageUrl="/images/home/B_397x930px.jpg" /> 
    <slide imageUrl="/images/home/C_397x930px.jpg" />
    <slide imageUrl="/images/home/D_397x930px.jpg" />
</slides>
```

My flash code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("/andiosp-flash.swf", "mymovie", "930", "398", "8", "#ffffff"); 
    so.addParam("quality", "high");
    so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    so.addParam("salign", "t");
    so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

I am using Liferay 6.1

Comment: Where do you store your images?

Comment: While creating wcd, image icon has options to upload images in respository.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your images in a theme, e.g. "your-theme", then you should try to access them by URLs:

```
/your-theme/images/home/an-image.jpg
```

This is the same for the other Liferay plugins.

The second way is to upload images while creating "Web Content Display" portlet:

1. Click "Image" button on the WYSIWYG toolbar
2. In tab "Image Info" click "Browse Server"
3. Then you'll be able to choose an existing image or upload new image in the repository
4. After you choose an image, you'll see the URL for this image in the field "URL"

You may also consider to upload images in "Documents and Media" portlet. Choose "Control Panel" -> "Documents and Media" and add your image as "Basic Document". Then you'll be able to click on uploaded image and get its URL provided by Liferay Portal.

Comment: My images are stored and displayed properly in WCD. I guess you have not read my question properly i want these images to be passed as source to my flash file.Which will show images in slides and each slides will have trasitions with the effect applied to it.

Comment: How does your SWF file get images: by link or in some other way (can't imagine some other way though)? I guess, it gets them from links that are specified in the XML file. Do you want to find a way to pass XML config to SWF file?

Comment: Yes i want a way so the images get pass to SWF(current) file.The present page is in asp.net where in they use xml as input to SWF file (which gives effect to the images).

Comment: So why can't you use XML file as input to SWF file in Liferay? You can store your XML in the theme, for example. Users will not be able to configure such WCD, of course, but do you need it? The best way is to create configurable portlet though.